# Parsing Pipe delimited message in Protobuf

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am new to Protobuf, I have been able to create .proto file for my messages. But I would like to know if there is an out of box support for parsing pipe delimited messages in protobuf.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. You will have to write custom code to convert from the "pipe delimited" format, as there is no standard for such a format.